# what is the best way to specify default value for a date parameter in ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a parameter in iReport Value_DT with Date data type.

If I'm using expression "new java.util.Date("01-SEP-14") as default value it works fine but this is hard code.

I'd like to use user defined function from Oracle DB, i.e. it might be similar to "new java.util.Date(new java.util.Date($F{GETACCOUNTINGDATE})) where GETACCOUNTINGDATE is oracle function.

With such syntax I have an error "The constructor Date(Timestamp) is undefined".

What should be changed in order to use function from DB in default parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of any way to do this directly in the default value expression without writing custom code. I believe you would need to write a custom class with a static method which connects to your database, calls `GETACCOUNTINGDATE`, and returns the date.  You could then, bundle this as a JAR, put it in your classpath and call this method in your Default Value Expression.

That's quite a bit of work though, so alternatively you may be able to 'recreate' the date using Java Date Function libraries.

We've used apache [dateUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html):

```
org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils.addMonths(new Date(),0))
```

I know a colleague has used jchronic to use strings and create dates.